# Discarding several log levels within a range with log4net

Tags: log4net

Say I set my log4net logger's `minLevel` and `maxLevel` to `FATAL` and `DEBUG` respectively, but under some scenario I want to mute the log-items written in the `WARN` level, and keep all the other levels in the range active.

Is it possible to somehow use 'discrete' levels of log-levels rather than specifying a range using `minLevel` and `maxLevel`?

I assume this should be simple, but I haven't found any log4net docs or examples dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `LevelMatchFilter` on your appender.

Example:

```xml
<appender name="FilteredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="DEBUG" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="INFO" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="ERROR" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    ...
</appender>
```

This example will only print DEBUG; INFO and ERROR messages. It is easy to customize this according to your needs.

Note: Do not forget the `DenyAllFilter` at the end.

Comment: Hey!

Thanks for the quick reply.
Can it be done programatically? i only found a way of changing the Logger's (root) log-level, not each appenders'.

Comment: sorry, I missed your comment. should be possible programatically as well. here you can see how to get to all appenders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016108/change-log4net-conversion-pattern-or-layout-at-runtime/3031867#3031867

Answer (score 2):

It's cool how log4net filters can all be combined to achieve the desired output. All log entries by default have a "Neutral" filter disposition and log4net by default logs all entries that are neutral.

What the `LevelRangeFilter` will do is if the level of the entry is in the range, it will set the filter disposition to "Accept" (or leave its disposition as it was if the `acceptOnMatch` parameter is set to `false`) and it will mark all entries not in the range with a disposition of "Deny".

The `LevelMatchFilter` will set the disposition for the filter specified in the `levelToMatch` parameter to "Accept" unless the `acceptToMatch` is set to `false`, then it will set matching entries to "Deny", unmatched entries will be left to what they were before.

So what you can do is use a combination of the two filters to get what you want:

```
<appender name="FilteredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
       <levelMax value="FATAL" />
       <levelMin value="ERROR" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="WARN" />
        <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
    </filter>
</appender>
```

This will allow you to easily toggle the warn level on and off. All entries outside of the range are already all marked as "Deny" and the `LevelMatchFilter` here will mark WARN level entries to Deny as well so the `DenyAllFilter` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Use LevelRangeFilter

```xml
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
   <levelMax value="FATAL" />
   <levelMin value="ERROR" />
</filter>
```

Comment: Hey, as that's the natural usage form, i tried this option but it forces me to log also the messages with levels *between* FATAL and ERROR, which i don't want (even though ERROR and FATAL are adjacent, the principle still applies).
Thanks anyway!