# Logging level isn't working

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have configured my application to use log4net as follows:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="SQL_Comandos" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="X" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO X ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[Usuario]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception, @usuario)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@usuario" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%X{usuario}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SQL_Hibernate" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="X" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO X ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level name="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="SQL_Comandos" />
    </root>
    <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false" >
      <level name="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="SQL_Hibernate" />
    </logger>
```

They work perfectly but all logging is saving DEBUG messages, even having configured not to do so. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work when you configure it like this:

```
<logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false" >
     <level value="ERROR" />
     ...
```

Note: that I use *value* instead of *name* in the level node (do this for the root "level" element as well). Turning on internal debugging would reveal this kind of problem.

Comment: That did it, thanks. Next time I'll be aware to use the internal debugging!

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, check your log appenders to see if they have something like the following configured:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="ALL"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: Hmm, not really, they don't have any filter.

Comment: @scardazzi - hmm...can you post the full log4net config?

Answer (score 0):

DEBUG is a lower level than INFO, so I suspect that the DEBUG messages are being logged because the root logger is set to log at the INFO level.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832082/discarding-several-log-levels-within-a-range-with-log4net) if you want to get the INFO messages but not the DEBUG messages.

Comment: I believe that DEBUG is a higher level, actually.

Comment: Confirmation: there goes the levels, ordered by priority:

Comment: ALL
DEBUG
INFO
WARN
ERROR
FATAL
OFF