# Is there a way to choose which log level i want to log with Log4Net?

Tags: .net, configuration, log4net

I saw that there is a way to log only one level type with the `levelToMatch`.

Is there a way to log `WARN` and `DEBUG` only for exemple? Only `INFO` and `ERROR`...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Discarding several log levels within a range with log4net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832082/discarding-several-log-levels-within-a-range-with-log4net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain several LevelMatchFilters as demonstrated in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832361/106567